# Single Regex to strip all HTML but the anchors

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Versions of this have been asked several times on here, and using those I was able to get two different ReGex statements.

One that strips all HTML

```
1. <[^>]*>
```

And one that strips everything but the anchor tags

```
2. <a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>
```

I have no hope of combining those to get a regex that strips all HTML but keeps the anchors so (1+!2). Therefore I'm currently going once trough my HTML with the first regex, and if I encounter a certain keyword that usually lives inside the anchors then I go trough the Body with the 2nd regex and combine both.

That clearly is not ideal and will most likely miss many anchors.

What would a single regex that matches all HTML but the anchors look like ? /1?!2/

Test data: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=105725 I need everything that is ALL CAPS and the anchor around it.

Comment: I do not see any question mark? There are expressions that might be doing that but please provide your tool/programming language as well.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/ISrz6O/1 for engines that support `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` but be warned that it is error-prone with nested structures (such as `HTML` that is).

Comment: @Jan my bad assuming Regex is the same everywhere. This one fails for me with a "Quantifier {x,y} following nothing." but thanks will look into it.

Comment: What about <[^a][^>]*>([^<]+)<\/[^a]> ?

Comment: @quant It matches only the p tags and definitely not the anchor. Added test data to help visualise the problem in my question.

Comment: Surprising that no one has yelled "Don't parse HTML with RegEx!" ;) [This question almost always comes up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @SamWhan I'd love to use a 3rd party tool or go about it in a different way but due to constraints I have to settle to using regex. Luckily my HTML isn't going to vary much and even in it's current state the code works I'm just trying to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disregarding my own comment ;) - Is this what you're after?

Replace

```
<((?!a|\/a)[^>]*)>\s*
```

with empty string.

The negative look-ahead after the opening `<` makes sure it ignores anchors.

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/opuTou/1).

Comment: Yep. If it works on the test data, which it did, it is what I'm after. Thank you.

Comment: Certainly <((?!a|\/a)[^>]*)>\s* is a good start, so +1, however it is more tricky in detail. If you have a text like <html><alt>asdf</alt><a href="foo">goog</a></html> the <alt> or any other tag starting with "<a" will be matched.

Comment: @quant Apart from span, head, meta and the usual suspects none of my html tags start with a, let alone contain a. So for my particular case it works perfectly.

Comment: @quant It could be enhanced to not match `alt` and likes simply by adding a word boundary - `<((?!a\b|\/a\b)[^>]*)>\s*`

Comment: Sam you're a hero ... (but wait a minute, wasn't there already a hero named sam? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_%28computer_worm%29 )